# Building different Solution Configuration in Appveyor for each platform

Tags: appveyor

I am attempting to add Linux building and testing to a C# library I maintain. One library in the solution requires WinForms and so cannot be build on Linux. I added a `ReleaseNoGui` configuration to my solution, and I would like Linux to build that rather than `Release`. Is this possible? This is what I've tried, but it is still building `Release`.

```
(…)

image: 
  - Visual Studio 2019
  - Ubuntu1804

configuration: Release

(…)

build:
  project: MySolution.sln
  parallel: true
  verbosity: minimal
  publish_nuget: true
  publish_nuget_symbols: false


for:
  - 
    matrix:
      only:
        - image: Visual Studio 2019

    deploy:
      - provider: NuGet
        name: nuget_release
        api_key:
(snipped...)
  -
    matrix:
      only:
        - image: Ubuntu1804

    configuration: ReleaseNoGui
```

Answer (score 2):

`for.matrix` specializes configs based on environment variables. Currently, `image` is unsupported environment variable.

To achieve what you want you can use the following `appveyor.yml` config instead:

```
environment:
  matrix:

  # Windows job
  - job_name: Windows build
    appveyor_build_worker_image: Visual Studio 2019

  # Linux job
  - job_name: Linux build
    appveyor_build_worker_image: Ubuntu1804

matrix:
  fast_finish: true

configuration: Release

build:
  project: MySolution.sln
  parallel: true
  verbosity: minimal
  publish_nuget: true
  publish_nuget_symbols: false

for:
-
  matrix:
    only:
      - job_name: Windows build

  deploy:
    - provider: NuGet
      name: nuget
-
  matrix:
    only:
      - job_name: Linux build

  configuration: ReleaseNoGui
```

Comment: I appreciate the input, but it isn't working. Linux still builds release.

Answer (score 1):

After reading Feodor's answer, I experimented with `environment.matrix` and added the `configuration` to the `environment.matrix` item, and came up with:

```
environment:
  matrix:

  # Windows job
  - job_name: Windows build
    appveyor_build_worker_image: Visual Studio 2019
    configuration: Release

  # Linux job
  - job_name: Linux build
    appveyor_build_worker_image: Ubuntu1804
    configuration: ReleaseNoGui

matrix:
  fast_finish: true

build:
  project: MySolution.sln
  parallel: true
  verbosity: minimal
  publish_nuget: true
  publish_nuget_symbols: false

for:
-
  matrix:
    only:
      - job_name: Windows build

  deploy:
    - provider: NuGet
      name: nuget
```

which builds Linux with the correct configuration.